# Functional Programming: Are maps sequential? Implications for closures

Tags: functional-programming, closures, julia, higher-order-functions

I will illustrate with Julia:

Suppose I have a function counter() that is a closure.

```
function mycl()                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        state=0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        function counter()                                                                                                                                                                                         
                state=state+1                                                                                                                                                                                      
        end                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

Now suppose I create the function mycoutner:

```
mycounter=mycl()
```

and now map this function over an array of length 10, with all elements being 1.

```
map(x->x+mycounter(),ones(1:10))
```

The output is as follows:

```
julia> map(x->x+mycounter(),ones(1:10))
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
```

It appears the function is applied sequentially over the to-be-mapped array.

Ultimately I am trying to avoid for loops, but with the local state variable of the closure mutating state, I need this to be applied sequentially. This seems to be the case, is this an adopted standard? (haven't tested the equivalent R version using *apply). And is this really "functional" because the local state variable is mutating?

Comment: This is the case with map. If you try with pmap instead you will see that your output will be something like  [2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4] etc, depending on the number of processes you define. And, yes, given your function has state, it is not functional, and the output in this case is completely unpredictable.

Comment: You should be using `reduce`/`fold` (whatever it's called in Julia) for things that need to be done sequentially, not `map`. The purpose of `map` is to create a new container, not carry out side effects.

Answer (score 4):

The current Julia implementation of `map` does apply its function argument to its collection argument(s) in order, although that is not an explicitly documented feature. In the future, evaluation order might change when multithreading becomes a non-experimental language feature, but that won't happen without warning. It's also likely that it will occur not by changing the behavior of `map`, but either as an opt-in feature – e.g. via `tmap` for "threaded map" – or as an optimization in cases where the compiler knows that the function being mapped is purely functional.

Comment: There is a `pmap` function which does just that, so I think it's a reasonable assumption that map will always be sequential. Also I would be very surprised if there wasn't *already* an optimisation for pure functions, since checking that is very easy.

Comment: The `pmap` function is for distributed parallel map, not for threading map in the current process. (Of course, one might want both, but that's an API design issue for the future.) There is no optimization to run pure functions across multiple threads since running Julia code in threads other than the main one is still an experimental feature (although an increasingly stable one).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question first, no, your code is not purely functional since it mutates state.

As for the first question, it depends on each language.  In Scheme, [R7RS](http://www.r7rs.org/) says "[t]he map procedure applies `proc` element-wise to the elements
of the `list`s and returns a list of the results, *in order*" (page 51, emphasis by me), where it seems somewhat ambiguous whether "in order" refers to the order of the lists or that of the *elements* of the lists (perhaps the former).  In OCaml, the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALmap) says that `List.map` "applies function `f` to `a1`, ..., `an`, and builds the list `[f a1; ...; f an]` with the results returned by `f`" which is also ambiguous but its [implementation](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml) is written explicitly sequentially using `let` as `a::l -> let r = f a in r :: map f l`.

Comment: R7RS says just after your quote that "[t]he dynamic order in which `proc` is applied to the elements of the `list`s is unspecified."

Answer (score 1):

The pure functional function you are looking for is an "accumulating map", which avoids state, instead threading an accumulative parameter. See for example the various [haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:7) implementations.

This function is fairly straightforward to implement in Julia also, though it can be argued that a for loop is more appropriate. In any event, a for loop with a single mutable state variable is far better than using a higher-order function with a closure that mutates state, as in the former the mutation is obvious and contained, whereas in the latter the mutation is unclear when calling the `map` function.